# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel Error with Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, interop, excel-interop

I'm creating a windows service that will create excel sheets, I've used Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel but got this Exception 
        `Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE`
I've attached a photo here

[Exception photo attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4tKz.png)

```
public void insertIntoSheet(string Name, DataTable dt)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

    if (xlApp == null)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("Excel is not properly installed!!");
        return;
    }
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
    Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
    object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
    xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
    for (int i = 1, j = 0; j < dt.Rows.Count; i++, j++)
    {
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1] = dt.Rows[j][0].ToString();
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 2] = dt.Rows[j][1].ToString();
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 3] = dt.Rows[j][2].ToString();
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 4] = dt.Rows[j][3].ToString();
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 5] = dt.Rows[j][4].ToString();
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 6] = dt.Rows[j][5].ToString();
    }
    //xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Sheet 1 content";

    xlWorkBook.SaveAs(String.Format("d:\\{0}.xls", Name), Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
    xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
    xlApp.Quit();

    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
    releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
    releaseObject(xlApp);
    Class_Library.WriteErrorLog("Inserting the sheet method finished");
    //MessageBox.Show("Excel file created , you can find the file d:\\csharp-Excel.xls");
}

private void releaseObject(object obj)
{
    try
    {
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
        obj = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        obj = null;
        Class_Library.WriteErrorLog(ex.Message);
        //MessageBox.Show("Exception Occured while releasing object " + ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        GC.Collect();
    }
}
```

NOTES: I've used the same code as a test in windows application and it worked as expected.
I've tried to write `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();` and also tried to use the Name Excel only like `Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();`

Comment: Office programs in general are highly incompatible with the service session and Microsoft *strongly* discourages the practice.  The error code just tells you that it crashed while starting up, it doesn't tell you why it crashed.  For which there are many possible reasons, none that you can ever see.  Which is why Microsoft discourages it :)

Comment: Exactly mate, but it did work on windows application with button click action what would prevent it on windows service

Comment: Then it runs in the user's session, Office programs were certainly designed to support that since that's they way they always run.  Biggest hangups with the service session are a very small desktop heap (since services are not expected to create UI), trouble with the user account they run with, undiagnosable printing mishaps and counter-measures in later Office versions that detect they run in session 0 and refuse to start up.

Comment: As @HansPassant pointed out, you are doing what is the so called "server side Office automation", https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757 Tons of materials show it a dead end.

Comment: So, If they run at session 0 how can i manage its session is it possible, please help didn't solve it yet i'm stuck at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Try Edit DCOMConfig

1.In DCOMCNFG, right click on the My Computer and select properties.

2.Go to Component /MyComputer/DCOMConfig

3.Go to Microsoft Excel Application property Security

4.In launch and Activation Permissions, click "Custamize" and add Network 
Service to it and give it "Local launch" and "Local Activation" permission. give same As Acess Permissions and cofiguration Permissions Press OK and thats it. You can run my application now.

Comment: I did what you told me added a Network Service and gave it all the permissions, and gave every group and every person all the permissions possible :) but still the same exception. Thanks for your time @mwisnicki

Answer (score 0):

Go to Excel's options / trust center / Macro settings and check "Trust access to the VBA project object model"

Comment: Thanks for your time @GeorgeT I did what you told me but still the same Exception.